# Empty cells in InAppSettingsKit settings window

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, inappsettingskit

I need to show settings screen within my app, so I use `InAppSettingsKit` to implement this. I use storyboards in my app, so I created a `UITableViewController` with `IASKAppSettingsViewController` super class. In this class I didn't implement any other special methods except `settingsViewControllerDidEnd:`. The problem is I need to hide empty cells in my table view (I have only two parameters in settings, so the whole remaining screen is full of empty cells). It means that the remaining part of the screen should be just empty, without empty cells, and with grey background (as in Settings.app).
I can make `UIView` with empty frame as footer view of `UITableView`, but it's not the best solution - background color of footer remains to be white as in normal table view. What's the best way to limit number of cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the Style property for my `UITableView` to Grouped in Interface Builder, and it resolved my problem.